# Request parameter if struts2 if tag

Tags: struts2, tags

I have another probably basic problem. happy if u can help.

there is a request parameter 'action'. if I write :

```
<label><s:property value="%{#parameters.action}"/></label>
```

the value appears (it is 1)

So itry to test now :

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.action == '1'}">YES 1</s:if><s:else>NOT 1</s:else>
```

NOT 1 appears.

I have tries all the syntaxes I found on the net for the test. Nothing changes, NOT 1 still displays

Thank you

Comment: have you set those parameter in your action class? can you show the Action class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because:

- the value of `%{#parameters.action}` is an array, not a single value, and
- the value will be type-converted to a number (not sure why; need to look in to that)

The correct expression would be:

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.action[0] == 1}">YES 1</s:if><s:else>NOT 1</s:else>
```

Comment: @mlwacosmos Then you'll need to provide more details, 'cuz I'm pretty sure the above works, and I understand precisely *why* it works.

Comment: I tried again and this time it works like Dave said.....and it does not work anymore like I said... I dont know why it did work because you are right normally it is an array

Comment: @mlwacosmos Glad you got it working--when that happens to me it's usually because I forgot to deploy a JSP and/or class file :/

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression would be:

`<s:if test="#parameters.action[0] == 1">YES 1</s:if><s:else>NOT 1</s:else>`

The request parameters is a map of [Strinf, String[]], So you have to access it like above